# Status 400 when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, spring, react-native

I am trying to build a simple React application which will return the JSON of a particular movie  by entering in its ID into the form and make a get request for it to the backed when a button is clicked. I would like to be able to see the JSON data in postman when I enter localhost://3000

However, when I currently click the button I am getting the following error Please see the images below

[Error Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7B8s.png)
[Error trace 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkej0.png)

**Please see my Spring backend below**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE}, allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieResource {

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/{movieId}")
    public Movie getMovieInfo(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) {
        MovieSummary movieSummary = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieId + "?api_key=" +  apiKey, MovieSummary.class);
        return new Movie(movieId, movieSummary.getTitle(), movieSummary.getOverview());

    }
}
```

**Please see my React front end code below**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Card,Form,ButtonGroup,Button,Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from "axios";

export default class MovieList extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
var config = { headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}};
this.state = this.startState;
}
startState = {id: ""};


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const id = {
      id: this.state.id
    }

    axios.get("http://localhost:8082/movies/" + id, this.config)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
        window.location = "/retrieve" //This line of code will redirect you once the submission is succeed
      })
      .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error has been caught: " + error);
                console.log(error);
            });

  }
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      id: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
  const {id} = this.state
    return (
    <Card className = {"border border-dark bg-dark text-white"}>
      <Card.Header> Get Json </Card.Header>
      <Form>
      <Card.Body>
      <Form.Group as = {Col}>
      <Form.Label> Customer ID </Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
      type = "test"
      placeholder = "Enter ID"
      value={id}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
       />
      <Form.Text className = "text-muted" >
      Press Get Json to receive JSON Data
      </Form.Text>
      </Form.Group >
      </Card.Body>
      <Card.Footer style = {{"textAlign": "right"}}>
      <Button onClick = {this.handleSubmit}
      size = "m"
      variant = "success"
      type = "submit" >
      Get Json
      </Button>
      </Card.Footer>
      </Form>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You're sending an `object` as the `movieId` param, whereas on your back end it's expecting a `String`. Try changing the line from `axios.get("http://localhost:8082/movies/" + id` to `axios.get("http://localhost:8082/movies/" + this.state.id`

Comment: That worked thank you so much!!!!! One more question if I may or if you have time. When the request goes through it goes to the retrieve page but the data doesn't show in postman have you any  idea off the top of you head how I could display this information in postman? All that's showing is the HTML.

Comment: I am not sure, since I don't have experience with `Java Spring`, but I assume it's got to do something with this line: `return new Movie(movieId, movieSummary.getTitle(), movieSummary.getOverview());`